# Is it possible to run docker image (linux containers based) locally on windows

Tags: docker

I build a docker image in windows using linux based containers. Now when I try to run it, it runs successfully on `127.0.0.1:5000`. But when I try to test it in the browser, it does not work.

I run `docker images` to see the built images. The image `gaitimg:V1` which I want to run on localhost, is present there.

I try to run it using the following command:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 gaitimg:V1 .
```

It runs successfully! However, I cannot run it in the browser in Windows.

Comment: Are you using Docker Toolbox or Docker Desktop?

Comment: I am using Docker Desktop

Comment: could you describe what you are seeing? What does "I cannot run it in the browser in Windows? look like?

Comment: When I type http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in the browser. The response I get is "This page is not working"